# Providing proper security for SAML service provider

Tags: security, single-sign-on, saml, adfs

I'm adding SSO feature to my service to allow customers login with their AD accounts. To provide this I use SAML component from [componentpro.com](http://www.componentpro.com/saml.net/)
What is correct way to perform security interaction:

1. From IdP side: what should customer provide to my service besides IdP url? Any certificate that just contains public key?
2. From SP side: what should I provide to customer?
3. Choosen SAML tool uses certificates to sign SAML request to IdP and to decrypt assertion from IdP. What are that certificates (from previous questions)? Is it the same certificate for signing and decrypting?

Update: useful [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/382966/purpose-of-the-x509-certificate-in-metadata-files-on-the-idp-side-sso-structure) about using certificates in SAML communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Normaly this is set up using a SAML metadata file that contains the IDP endpoints, keys etc. Your service then sends a similar metadata file with information about your service to the IDP
2. If the customer is the IDP then as above you usually provide them with a metadata file.
3. It is gennerally a bad idea to use the same key for signing and encryption. Read the discussions [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12090/using-the-same-rsa-keypair-to-sign-and-encrypt) and [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/why-should-one-not-use-the-same-asymmetric-key-for-encryption-as-they-do-for-sig)

Comment: Thanks for response. It's now clear to me.
Also added useful link to read to question.

Comment: Good to hear. Good luck